# Customizing Insert Value Textbox in functions.php (Theme File Editor) Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Hi it is possible to customize value in textbox in functions.php?

This is the current HTML code from WP Job Manager Plugin

```
<input type="text" class="input-text" name="application" id="application" placeholder="https://" value="" maxlength="" required="" data-gtm-form-interact-field-id="0">
```

and I code like this in functions.php, but it's not working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#application").val("https://");
});
```

Or it is possible to add value textbox in CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this two ways:

**#1 - Using `wp_footer` hook (least recommended way) in your `functions.php`:**

```
function my_js_code() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($){
            $("#application").val("https://");
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_js_code' );
```

---

**#2 - Creating a JS file and enqueuing it(recommended way)**

In `functions.php` file:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_js_script' );

function my_js_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'your-script', //-- a unique name for your script
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my-script.js', //-- JS file location in your theme. Use get_stylesheet_directory_uri() if you are in a child theme
        array('jquery') //-- our code has jQuery dependency
    );
}
```

And in the `/js/my-script.js` :

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("#application").val("https://");
});
```